# Cordova iOS 10.3.1 failing ajax query without any error report

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ajax, cordova

I've been using in a cordova App for iOS and Android the following sync library successfully for the last couple of years
https://github.com/abeauseigle/TodoApp

Suddenly, it seems in connection with iOS >10.3 update, I started facing issues: 
everything works well properly in
- Ripple
- Android Emulator
- iOS Simulator

On **real device** iPhone 5 with iOS 10.3.1 the websql part is not executed.

I tend to think that the whole ajax call does not happen in a whole.

Here the call:

```
_sendDataToServer: function(dataToSync, uploadProgressCallBack, downloadProgressCallBack, finishCallBack) {
    var self = this;

    var XHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),
    data = JSON.stringify(dataToSync);
    console.log("Line 261 clientData:",data);
    XHR.overrideMimeType = 'application/json;   charset=UTF-8';

    XHR.open("POST", self.serverUrl, true);
    //XHR.timeout = 300000; //default: no timeout
    XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var serverAnswer="";
        if(4 === XHR.readyState) {
            try{
                serverAnswer = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
                console.log("Line 293 Server answered:",serverAnswer);  
            } catch(e) {
                serverAnswer = XHR.responseText;
                console.log('e.message: ',e.message); 
                console.log("Line 297 Server answered:",serverAnswer);       
            }

            self.log('Line 300 Server answered: ');
            self.log(serverAnswer);
            //I want only json/object as response
            if(XHR.status == 200 && serverAnswer instanceof Object) {
                                    console.log("websqlsync ok"); 
                finishCallBack(serverAnswer);   
            } else {
                serverAnswer = {
                    result : 'ERROR',
                    status : XHR.status,
                    message : XHR.statusText
                };
                console.log("websqlsync PROBLEM"); 
                                    finishCallBack(serverAnswer);
            }
        }
    };

    XHR.send(data);

}
```

Of all the console logs I just see the first:

```
Line 261 clientData:
```

The problem happens only on REAL DEVICE...
any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `console.log("Line 261 clientData:",data);` remove ',' and place + sign in every console.log ? its a wrong syntax.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's wrong. You use "+" if you want to create a string. If "data" is an object you use "," so it remains an object.

Comment: But it will break your log, it will not access anything after comma so you need to use + sign to print your data objects.

Comment: I can ensure it does: I used the same code for two years :-)

Comment: My mistake, you are right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and wrong attempts I found that setting a timeout solve the issue:

```
XHR.timeout = 300000;
```

I hope this helps someone else (certainly will be a reminder for me).